# facing error of debug freemarker.cache

Tags: java, eclipse, frameworks

> [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache  - Couldn't find template in cache for
>   "index.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
>
> [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache  -
>   TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("index_en.ftl"): Not found
>
> [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache  -
>   TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("index.ftl"): Found
>
> [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache  - Loading template for
>   "index.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from
>   "jar:file:/C:/DRIVE/PEDAGOGY%20TEST%20CODE/Library/extentreports-3.0.7.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/index.ftl"

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)